# Como crear relaciones en EF Core a partir de un modelo de entidad

Tags: base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

como puedo crear relaciones con codigo EF

Cliente -> Registro del cliente
PersonalInformation - > Informacion personal del cliente
PaymentHistory -> Reportes de pagos de condominio

```
public class Client{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PersonalInformation{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PaymentHistory{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PayNumber { get; set; }
    public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
    public double CreditBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que quieres relacionar?

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas facil es relacionarlas en tu gestor de base de datos y luego cuando la generes con Scaffold-DbContext te va a generar automaticamente las relaciones, pero debes de tener las claves foraneas definidas.

Si vas a crear tus modelos desde el proyecto (CodeFirst) entonces puedes agregarles manualmente las propiedades para relacionarlas.

Ejemplo

Si queres relacionar Client y PaymentHistory seria de esta forma

```
 public class Client{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PaymentHistory> PaymentHistories { get;set;}
    }

    public class PaymentHistory{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PayNumber { get; set; }
        public double CurrentBalance { get; set; }
        public double CreditBalance { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
    }
```

Luego en el context configuras la relación usando [fluent api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
 modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentHistory>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Client)
            .WithMany(c =>c.PaymentHistories)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ClientId);
}
```

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/modeling/relationships) esta la documentación oficial donde te explica las diferentes forma de relacionar las entidades.

Luego si quieres obtener la lista de clientes con su historial de pago lo haces de esta forma

```
var clientesConPagos=context.Client.include(p=>p.PaymentHistories).ToList();
```